# Question regarding Lebesgue outer measure.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given $m\geq1$, $0\leq s<\infty$, $0<\delta\leq\infty$ and $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{m}$ define: $$\mathcal{H}_{\delta}^{s}\left(A\right)=\inf\left\{ {\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}d\left(B_{n}\right)^{s}\,|\,\left\{ B_{n}\right\} _{n\in\mathbb{N}}}\:\mbox{is a covering of }A\:\mbox{and }d\left(B_{n}\right)<\delta\,\forall\, n\geq1\right\}$$
For ease of notation this refers to countable coverings but it also includes finite coverings. Now I've shown the following two things:

1. For all $m\geq1$, $0\leq s<\infty$, $0<\delta\leq\infty$ this defines an external measure on $\mathbb{R}^{m}$.
2. For all $0\leq s<\infty$ and $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{m}$ the limit $ \mathcal{H}^{s}\left(A\right)=\lim\limits _{\delta\downarrow0}\mathcal{H}_{0}^{s}\left(A\right)$ exists.

I'm now trying to show these following two things:

1. For all $ 0\leq s<\infty\quad$ $\mathcal{H}^{s}$ is an external metric measure on $\mathbb{R}^{m}$.
2. $\mathcal{H}^{0}$ is the counting measure on $\mathbb{R}^{m}$

Here is what I know so far regarding each of these goals:

1. I want to show that for each $A,B\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{m}$ if $dist(A,B)>0$ then $$\mathcal{H}^{s}(A\cup B)=\mathcal{H}^{s}(A)+\mathcal{H}^{s}(B)$$I know that $dist(A,B)>0$ is equivalent to $\overline{A}\cap\overline{B}=\emptyset$ so I assume I should use that somehow but I'm not sure how.
2. I've shown it works for finite sets but I'm having trouble with infinite sets. Obviously for $s=0$ we get that $\mathcal{H}_{\delta}^{0}\left(A\right)$ is a function only of the number of sets in the covering for which the infima is obtained. What I want to show is that given an infinite subset $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{m}$ as $\delta\downarrow0$ the number of sets required in order to cover $A$ by sets of diameter less than $\delta$ goes to infinity. 
   At first this struck me as a bit odd since for a compact infinite set we know that for each $\delta>0$ there is a finite $\delta$-net covering $A$ but then I realized that doesn't mean the number of sets in these nets doesn't go to infinity.

Anyway, I'd really appreciate some thick hints or a full proof of these two claims, I've already spent a couple of hours wrecking my head over it alone :)

Comment: $\operatorname{dist}(A,B) > 0$ is stronger than $\overline{A}\cap\overline{B} = \varnothing$. Consider only coverings with sets of diameter $< \frac12\operatorname{dist}(A,B)$ to show $\mathcal{H}^s$ is metric.

Comment: @DanielFischer Could you slightly elaborate please?

Comment: If you only consider coverings with sets of small enough diameter, no covering set can intersect both, $A$ and $B$. So if you consider only coverings where no set lies entirely in the complement of $A\cup B$, such a covering naturally decomposes into a pair of coverings of $A$ resp. $B$.

Comment: I see where you're going. There's still one thing I'm unsure of. $\mathcal{H}_{\delta}^{s}$ is defined as an infimum on all coverings and if you restrict yourself to looking at coverings by sets of smaller diameter the infimum increases. Considering that why is it justified to consider only coverings by sets of diameter $<\frac{1}{2}\mbox{dist}\left(A,B\right)$

Comment: Actually never mind, I can just start looking at the limit starting with values of $\delta$ such that $\delta<\frac{1}{2}d\left(A,B\right)$ and then I have no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (2) - for any $n$, an infinite set $A$ contains a subset of cardinality $n$. So as $H^0$ is an outer measure, $H^0(A)\geq n$. As this holds for all $n$, we are done.

Comment: Wow that is so much simpler than my approach...

Comment: I did actually spend a couple of minutes messing around with trying to get the number of sets required to go to 0, then I realised the main key for the finite case (choose a delta less than the minimum distance between any 2 points) no longer works.

Comment: Ye that's where I got stuck also... 
Really what you suggested is a super elegant solution, kudos.